# CI/CD Gitlab with Harbor Registry

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, harbor

I have 3 server

1. Gitlab
2. Gitlab Runner
3. Harbor Registry

When I run CI/CD on Gitlab but it cannot login to Harbor Registry. This is error.

```
Get https://172.21.5.247/v1/users/: x509: cannot validate certificate for 172.21.5.247 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs
```

When I try login docker on server Gitlab and Gitlab Runner is successfully. I added "insecure-registries" to two server.
[image]

.gitlab.ci.yml file

```
image: docker:18-git

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://localhost:2375

stages:
  - build
  - push
services:
  - name: docker:dind
    command: ["--insecure-registry=172.21.5.247:443"]

before_script:
  - echo $HARBOR_USERNAME
  - echo -n $HARBOR_PASSWORD | docker login -u $HARBOR_USERNAME -p $HARBOR_PASSWORD $HARBOR_REGISTRY
  - docker version
  - docker info

after_script:
  - docker logout $HARBOR_REGISTRY

Build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker pull $HARBOR_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest || true
    - >
      docker build
      --pull
      --cache-from $HARBOR_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
      --tag $HARBOR_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA .
    - docker push $HARBOR_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA

Push_When_tag:
  stage: push
  only:
    - tags
  script:
    - docker pull $HARBOR_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
    - docker tag $HARBOR_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA $HARBOR_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    - docker push $HARBOR_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
```

It have error in docker login.

Comment: Did you get round that? What was the fix?

Answer (score 1):

Since Harbor 2.2 minor release you are able to create a harbor robot login,
afterwards write these credentials to  **Settings**->**CI/CD**->**Variables**:

`-HARBOR_ROBOT_USER` (Important! you have to escape the $ in the robot username eg. robot$$myuser [robot account name containing "$" will cause...](https://github.com/goharbor/harbor/issues/9732#issuecomment-552708837))

```
-HARBOR_ROBOT_PASSWORD
```

Now you are able to use these Variables in before script as follows

```
- HARBOR_ROBOT_PASSWORD=${HARBOR_ROBOT_PASSWORD}
- HARBOR_ROBOT_USER=${HARBOR_ROBOT_USER}

## login process to harbor docker registry
  echo $HARBOR_ROBOT_PASSWORD | docker login --username $HARBOR_ROBOT_USER  --password-stdin ${HARBOR_REGISTRY}
```